# How to create non-anonymous rooms in Ejabberd

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd

I would like to create a non-anoymous room (muc) in Jabber (Ejabberd). I can create an anonymous room, but how can i make it non-anonymous?

I have read http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0045.html but they only describe what non-anonymous rooms, not how to create it.

I want the members to see each other's normal JIDs as opposed to conference JIDs with a nick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [official guide](http://www.process-one.net/en/ejabberd/guide_en#htoc49) - set `anonymous` to `false` using your chat client (assuming you have admin rights):

> {default_room_options, [ {OptionName, OptionValue}, ...]}
>
> This module option allows to define the desired default room options. Note that 
>   the creator of a room can modify the options of his room at any time using a XMPP 
>   client with MUC capability. The available room options and the default values are:
>
> {anonymous, true|false}
>
> ```
>   The room is anonymous: occupants don’t see the real JIDs of other occupants. 
>   Note that the room moderators can always see the real JIDs of the occupants.
> ```

Comment: This is what i ended up doing. But i'd still be interested to know how to create non-anonymous rooms on a case by case basis, using only XML

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a gui to configure this and similar settings of muc rooms, you might want to install [Psi](http://psi-im.org/), connect to your server, join/create a room with service discovery and find that small arrow in the top-right corner of the room window. An enabled XML console is really helpful.